# Finding the eccentricity of the hyperbola $\left|\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2}\right|-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2}=1$

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Find the eccentricity of the given hyperbola:
$$\left|\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2}\right|-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2}=1$$

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv3W6.jpg))

Comment: [5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=equation+of+hyperbola+foci+%28-1%2C-1%29+and+%283%2C2%29+with+eccentricity+5)

Comment: @Jan-Magnus Økland How???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the absolute value does not matter, because square roots are always positive. Because of the distance formula, this means:
Distance from $(x,y)$ to $(3,2)$ minus distance from $(x,y)$ to $(-1,-1)$. Therefore, by the definition of a hyperbola, the foci are $(3,2),(-1,-1)$, and the distance from the center to the vertices is $\frac{1}{2}$.

This center is at the midpoints of the 2 foci, or $(1,0.5)$. The distance from a focus to the center is 2.5, by the distance formula.

Therefore, the eccentricity is $\frac{\mathrm{distance}\:\mathrm{from}\:\mathrm{focus}\:\mathrm{to}\:\mathrm{center}}{\mathrm{\mathrm{distance}\:\mathrm{from}\:\mathrm{vertex}\:\mathrm{to}\:\mathrm{center}}}=\frac{\frac{5}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} = 5$

Hopefully this helps!